# php - stop php if empty textbox and process other html forms

Tags: php, html

Below is the code I have, which checks for if text box is empty then give warning beside text box once clicked on Submit.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {


    $fqdn = $_POST["fqdn"];
    $ip = $_POST["ip"];
    $fileText = $fqdn."\n".$ip;
    $file = fopen("inputFile.txt","w");
    fwrite($file, $fileText);
    fclose($file);
}
?>
 <form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "post">
            <table style= "width:400px">
                <tr class="spaceUnder">
                    <td><b>FQDN:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="fqdn" placeholder="server.domain.com"/></td>
                    <td>  <?php if(isset($_POST['fqdn']) && $_POST['fqdn'] == ''){ echo "<font color='red'>FQDN cannot be empty</font>";} ?> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="spaceUnder">
                    <td><b>IP:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="ip" placeholder="***.***.***.***"/></td>
                    <td>  <?php if(isset($_POST['ip']) && $_POST['ip'] == ''){ echo "<font color='red'>IP cannot be empty</font>"; } ?> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="2">
                    <input type = "submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
                   </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
```

After clicking on submit, the php is still going and writing to the file. If i give exit() or return false; at the below step:

```
<td>  <?php if(isset($_POST['fqdn']) && $_POST['fqdn'] == ''){ echo "<font color='red'>FQDN cannot be empty</font>"; exit();} ?> </td>
```

the form becomes incomplete, means, the IP textbox and submit button will not exist. Any way to make it right?

Comment: why you dont put that condition on submit code

Comment: if the value is empty echo the warning else execute the code

Comment: How can we print the warning beside the textbox if I have the code in the submit block. This cloud help.

Comment: You could add a variable there  like this $error . The first value of this is empty but if the value is emty to your submit code you assign to the error variable the message you wand, and will be dispayed on the textbox

Comment: Can u elaborate in answer? I am new to php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what we have here. We are making 2 variables that will dispay our errors. The variable in first place are emty because we dont know what we have post. After we post the data we can see if the post is emty or not. If the post is emty we assign an error message to the variable and dispay it to our table.

```
$error_FQDN = "";
$error_ip = "";

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if($_POST["fqdn"] == "" || $_POST["ip"] == ""){
        if($_POST["fqdn"] == ""){
            $error_FQDN = "FQDN cannot be empty!";
        }
        if($_POST["ip"] == ""){
            $error_ip = "IP cannot be empty!";
        }
    } else {
        $fqdn = $_POST["fqdn"];
        $ip = $_POST["ip"];
        $fileText = $fqdn."\n".$ip;
        $file = fopen("inputFile.txt","w");
        fwrite($file, $fileText);
        fclose($file);
    }
}

<form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "post">
    <table style= "width:400px">
        <tr class="spaceUnder">
            <td><b>FQDN:</b></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fqdn" placeholder="server.domain.com"/></td>
            <td><?php echo $error_FQDN ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="spaceUnder">
            <td><b>IP:</b></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ip" placeholder="***.***.***.***"/></td>
            <td><?php echo $error_ip ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="2">
            <input type = "submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: error_FQDN is displayed

Comment: have you put $error_FQDN at the begging of your code and assign it a emty value?

Comment: Yes. I have given it. Still that notice

Comment: Your html code is first and then the php code comes or i'am whrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
// Check for form submit and if fields aren't empty
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST['fqdn'] != "" && $_POST['ip'] != "") {
    $fqdn = $_POST["fqdn"];
    $ip = $_POST["ip"];
    $fileText = $fqdn."\n".$ip;
    $file = fopen("inputFile.txt","w");
    fwrite($file, $fileText);
    fclose($file);
}
```

By validating fqdn and ip, if values aren't empty, if case will be executed. Else it simply won't run.

Comment: wanted warning as well. Hope this will just check for empty fields.